# Jupyter Notebook: Error 500 while opening Python file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've downloaded Jupyter Notebook and tryed to make a new Python 3 file (Name: Letovo_olympiad.ipynb). Then I opened it and caught Error 500 (address: http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Downloads/Python%20files/Letovo_olympiad.ipynb).

Particular error info from terminal:

```
[E 13:35:28.142 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception GET /notebooks/Downloads/Python%20files/Letovo_olympiad.ipynb (::1)
HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='GET', uri='/notebooks/Downloads/Python%20files/Letovo_olympiad.ipynb', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1704, in _execute
result = await result
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 775, in run
yielded = self.gen.send(value)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/notebook/handlers.py", line 94, in get
self.write(self.render_template('notebook.html',
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/base/handlers.py", line 511, in render_template
return template.render(**ns)
File "/Users/alex0758/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1301, in render
self.environment.handle_exception()
File "/Users/alex0758/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 936, in handle_exception
raise rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/templates/notebook.html", line 1, in top-level template code
extends "page.html" %}
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/templates/page.html", line 154, in top-level template code
block header %}
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/templates/notebook.html", line 115, in block 'header'
for exporter in get_frontend_exporters() %}
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/notebook/handlers.py", line 40, in get_frontend_exporters
for name in get_export_names():
File "/Users/alex0758/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/base.py", line 147, in get_export_names
e = get_exporter(exporter_name)(config=config)
File "/Users/alex0758/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/base.py", line 106, in get_exporter
if getattr(exporter(config=config), "enabled", True):
File "/Users/alex0758/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 342, in __init__
super().__init__(config=config, **kw)
File "/Users/alex0758/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 118, in __init__
self._init_preprocessors()
File "/Users/alex0758/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 508, in _init_preprocessors
conf = self._get_conf()
File "/Users/alex0758/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 528, in _get_conf
if conf_path.exists():
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 1424, in exists
self.stat()
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 1232, in stat
return self._accessor.stat(self)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates/conf.json'
[E 13:35:28.143 NotebookApp] {
      "Host": "localhost:8888",
      "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/tree/Downloads/Python%20files",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    }
[E 13:35:28.143 NotebookApp] 500 GET /notebooks/Downloads/Python%20files/Letovo_olympiad.ipynb (::1) 52.210000ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree/Downloads/Python%20files
```

Then I made other types of files (e.g. text) and they have opened normaly. The problem happens only with Python 3 files.

Comment: The error log has `Permission denied: '/usr/local/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates/conf.json'`. Verify if you have access to this resource.

Answer (score 0):

just delete and download it again or you can just check whether your system had given access to make changes or give permission.